# Disclose a few missing git commits on my repo

Tags: git, github

My project folder is currently at the latest  (r41).

I remembered I was trying to commit some files for revision 38 to do the refactory but I had to do away with unpublished (not yet pushed) commits after I made a few other changes in the code and finally committed to make it r38 (I use git -reset soft HEAD~1).

I continued working on til project completion at r41. Now, I want to review some code and find old commits (r36, r37) are missing in [my repo](https://github.com/zenithtekla/asmx-data-retrieval/commits/master).

[image: reflog result]

I learned some about Git in the past but after some months diving into development with high focus, I appear to forget some Github knowledge and obviously want to cut it short with Github drama (too many commands and explanations, nor do they create confusion, they indeed cost time to attain a full comprehension and clarity to not enter a wrong command).

Cut to the chase, with my current situation I don't want to create any branch. I want to keep the same master and have r36, r37 displayed on my repo.
What git commands should I enter? Simple explanations, please. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the reflog, I think there were executions of a command similar to `git reset HEAD~1` after r37 (twice), and after r39. That would explain why the commits are missing from the `master` branch (`git reset --hard HEAD~1` will have the effect of moving the HEAD pointer to the previous commit, effectively removing the last commit from the current branch) (Apparently, that command was previously used to modify r34). Some source code may, or may not, be missing (depending on whether `--hard` was specified in `git reset`)

Recommendations for the future:

- Use `git reset --hard`, or better, [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean), when you want to clean up your workspace - there is no need to specify a revision;
- Use `git commit --amend`, or [`git rebase -i`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) if you want to fix an unpublished commit;

Now, the problem is that the commits corresponding to r36, r37 and r39 are not part of the `master` branch on your local repository. However, unless you are very unlucky (or ran a [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) that can prune dangling commits), the commit data should still be there.

I think (please backup your git repository before executing any commands an internet stranger gives you) that [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) should fix your issue, by reintroducing corresponding code (in newly created commit objects).

So, the following command should introduce new commits, that would match the missing revisions:

```
git cherry-pick 52b140c 6fca0fa ca7ee4f
```

After that you can push that to github - the commits with the right messages will appear at the end of the `master` branch.

**Edit**: I had written the previous answer on the assumption that `--hard` resets had been done. However, if the reset was a soft one, then that means that the changes in these commits had already been done. In that case restoring the commits is simply a way to reintroduce these commits in the history - that means that there will be a history rewrite, which can be a big hassle if the repository has already been pulled by other people.

If you can do history rewriting, then, after committing any outstanding changes, and discarding the cherry picks (e.g. by running `git reset --hard 60c067e`, or by using the backup that I told you to make), you can run the following commands, to rebase the existing code upon the previously existing commits:

```
# This command will reintegrate r39
git rebase 6fca0fa

# This command will reintegrate r36 and r37
git rebase ca7ee4f
```

After that, you will be able to push to github, but you will have to use the `--force` option (as some existing, published commits, will be erased)

Comment: hello Jean,
Thank you for your input. 
As you analysed, I used `git -reset soft HEAD~1`  3 times, resulting in missing 3 revisions, by moving the head (as if I understand correctly). 

With cherry-pick, I get the following errors

`$ git cherry-pick 52b140c aaabf0d 6fca0fa
error: could not apply 52b140c... r36 added few other tweaks on directive
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
`

Comment: @PristineKallio This error message means that you have merge conflicts from doing the cherry picks.  Do the conflicts you see seem resolvable to you?

Comment: I have files conflict when before and after refactory (r38) and if you check my repo right now, I've run into a new issue with duplication and old commits appearing at top. Too bad with my attempt resolving the issue, generating a new problem. @.@ :(

Comment: @PristineKallio: I have edited the answer for the case of a `--soft` reset (turns out, in that case, a cherry pick is counter productive), and I also realized that I made a mistake in the triplet of commits specified in the cherry pick.

Comment: Thank you for your second response. I fixed everything last night with reset --hard to the HEAD of r35 and did cherry-picking from there to restore the clone of r36, 37, and 39. I realised it is NOT possible to just cherry-pick them and insert them into their existing positions. With cherry-pick, they are restored at newly created commits which appear on top of r41. and I don't want that, so I had to rewrite history all the way from r35. I lost my notes and comments to old r36, r37, 39 anyway. new r36.. have diff hash.

Comment: @PristineKallio: Yes, in order to insert the commits at their original positions, a history rewrite would always have been necessary. History rewrites come with a cost (when you push a history rewrite, all the people that have previously pulled pre-rewrite commits have to take special precautions in order to avoid reintroducing them), and I was operating under the assumption that you were not necessarily in a position to do that.

Comment: new r36.. have diff hash (I meant SHA 6fca0fa ...)
I had an old link to that SHA and still able to revisit that one. I just don't understand why Github does NOT allow displaying old revisions (with those SHA) as they were there before a --soft reset, cherry-picking and showing them in any position, anywhere we like is better than having to push to the top of our branch/head though. Maybe, it is a timeline issue: history recording + file history (there come possible conflicts). Any insight from you ?